# Why chrome.storage.local.get can't execute in time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am writing an extension for Chrome, I hope by this plugin I can modify the chrome HTTP request headers.
so I want the user is able to customize their heads, then when chrome sends a HTTP request, first to intercept the request, then a custom configuration for users, according to the configuration modify the request headers, and then send.
But in this process, I encountered some problems when I intercepted chrome request, I will get this time the user configuration, but it seems to get the user configuration needs some time, always when there is access to the user configuration when the HTTP request has been away, I don't know. How can let users access the configuration of this operation is blocked, only when it gets done will intercept the HTTP request to let go
Here is my code to intercept the HTTP request:
(Please forgive my poor English :P, thank you very much~)

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
  var headers = details.requestHeaders,
  blockingResponse = {};
  // now I am trying to modify blockingRequest
  chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(results) {
    for(var result in results){
      headers.push({"name":result, "value":results[result]});
    }
  }); // but the code above is useless.
  // if you print the new headers , you will find the new headers doesn't change.
  blockingResponse.requestHeaders = headers;
  return blockingResponse;
},
{urls: [ "<all_urls>" ]},['requestHeaders','blocking']);
```